# Can anyone explain the output of the following code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

While practicing the list and dictionary I tried the following code but not understanding the output of it. Can you explain this?

```
list1 = []
json1 = {
    "key1": "",
    "key2": ""
}
json1['key2'] = 'value2'
list2 = ["list_item_1", "list_item2"]
for item in list2:
    json1['key1'] = item
    list1.append(json1)
print list1
```

Output I am getting is like:

```
[{'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'list_item2'}, {'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'list_item2'}]
```

According to my understanding, the output should be

```
[{'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'list_item1'}, {'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'list_item2'}]
```

or

```
[{'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'list_item2'}, {'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'list_item1'}]
```

My understanding is wrong somewhere but I want to know that what is wrong.
I am using **python 2.7.13** 64 bit on windows 10 platform.

It will be great if you can tell me the reason behind the difference between the output.

Thanks!

Comment: You are appending the same `dict` instance to `list1` for every iteration of the loop.

Comment: use `print()` between lines to see what you have in variables. It can help understand code.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
list1.append(json1)
```

you're appending the object `json1` to `list1`. In the next iteration of that loop, you change `json1`, and then append it *again* to `list1`. Note that you've added the same object to the loop twice, only having changed an attribute of that object in between.

So when you print the list, it prints the same object twice. To avoid this happening, you'll need to add a *separate but identical* copy of `json1` to your `list1` (so that when you later modify the original list, you're not modifying the copy that you've already added to the list). You can do this with the `dict.copy()` method:

```
for item in list2:
    json1['key1'] = item
    list1.append(json1.copy())
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your misunderstanding is from this line:

```
list1.append(json1)
```

This appends the *object* `json1` to `list`; you seem to expect it to take a snapshot of `json1`'s current value and put that *copy* into `list1`.  If you want that effect, use

```
list1.append(copy(json1))
```

However, this will copy only the top level of `json1`; if the dict contains objects, you'd need to `import copy` and then use `copy.deepcopy(json1)`.

Does that help clear up your understanding, or does it make it even more complex?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't understand how variables work in python. In python **everything** is an object and all variables are pointers to values. What this means is that when you do

```py
x = []
y = x
```

The variables `x` and `y` are pointing to the same list object. I can verify that by executing

```py
x is y  # True
```

and if I do

```py
x.append("foo")
y.append("bar")
print "x:", x
print "y:", y
```

The output is:

```
x: ["foo", "bar"]
y: ["foo", "bar"]
```

because `x` and `y` are pointing to the same list.

The same thing happens in your code.
When you do `list1.append(json1)`, `json1` is pointing to a dictionary and its value never changes (you never do `json1 = ...`), so the result is the same dictionary being appended to the list twice and any changes which are made to that dictionary are reflected in both list elements.

To get the result you expected, you need to copy the dictionary of `json1` and append the copy to the list. Replacing the line `list1.append(json1)` with `list1.append(dict(json1))` will give you the expected result because `dict()` creates a copy of that dictionary.